# C# Passing arrays between class A and Class B

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods

I am trying to get `array[i]` from class B to my class A.

In class B I have:

```
public array getArray() {
    return array[i];
}
```

How can I get the full `array` to make this work?

```
combobox1.items.add(getArray());
```

I am trying this, but it does not work. Can you please answer with a code sample that explains two methods in different classes that send and get `array[i]`.

Comment: Some *terrible* answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `class A` access to the entire array and not just a single value.  For example

```
class B {
  Object[] _array;
  public Object[] GetArray() {
    return _array;
  }
}
```

Now `class A` can consume all of the elements and fully populate the combo box

```
foreach (object element in classBInstance.GetArray()) {
  combobox1.Items.Add(element);
}
```

Comment: This is dirty. In object oriented world, you should never return your internal array directly. -1

Comment: @Al the user appears to be fairly new to the language and hence I'm opting for the most straight forward solution.

Comment: Actually the most straight forward code would be a property: public Object[] MyArray { get; private set; } in class B.

Comment: @knight0323 I'd avoid that because it's using a more advanced language feature.

Comment: OK, I think everyone here has some piece of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, so I will try to answer based on what I understood to be your problem.

```
class A 
{
    string[] array;
    public string[] GetArray() { return array; }
}
```

then you can write code like this to fill a combobox

```
A items = new A();
// fill in array in A
comboBox1.DataSource = items.GetArray();
```

or

```
foreach(string item in items)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add( item );
}
```

I do set lists using the `DataSource` member all the time, especially when going from `enum`s to strings.

**Example:**

```
comboBox1.DataSource = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.DayOfWeek));
```

Comment: The same as above: This is dirty. In object oriented world, you should never return your internal array directly. -1

Comment: @AlKepp you do when you care about speed, and not have to copy values 10,000 times a second. Not everyone is building Banking code, that needs this level of security. Spare me the OOP idealism, and answer realistically the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

You have to iterate through your array:

```
foreach(var item in GetArray())
{
     combobox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Well if i understood correctly


foreach(var item in ClassB.GetArray())
{
     combobox1.Items.Add(item);
}

with reference to classb?

Comment: The same as above: This is dirty. In object oriented world, you should never return your internal array directly. -1

Answer (score -1):

Well your example you have i but its not initiated anywhere, you would need to pass it like this:

```
public array getArray(int i)
{
    return array[i];
}



combobox1.items.add(getArray(5));
```

Comment: The same as above: This is dirty. In object oriented world, you should never return your internal array directly. -1

Answer (score -2):

Although other answers are technically working, in my opinion one should never return an internal array directly, as it goes against good practices in object oriented programming. So I would either implement IEnumerable interface in that class or at least return IEnumerator or IEnumerable which would make the returned collection read-only.

Example:

```
class ClassB {
  int[] array;
  public IEnumerable<int> GetValues() { return array; }
}

class ClassA {
  void DoTheJob(ClassB source) {
    foreach(int item in source.GetValues()) {
      combobox.Items.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Another clean solution is to add "Do with values" functionality to class B. Then we simply provide delegate. Example:

```
class ClassB {
  int[] array;
  public void DoWithValues(Action<int> action) {
    foreach(int item in array) action(item);
  }
}

class ClassA {
  ComboBox combobox;
  void DoTheJob(ClassB source) {
    source.DoWithValues(item => combobox.Items.Add(item));
  }
}
```

The next (third) example shows how to make whole ClassB enumerable with foreach:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  ClassB b = new ClassB();
  foreach(int i in b) Console.Write(i + " ");
}

class ClassB : IEnumerable<int> {

  int[] array;

  public ClassB() {
    array = new int[20];
  }

  public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
    return (array as IEnumerable<int>).GetEnumerator();
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return array.GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

**update:** As ja72 shown, this simple technique which just publishes enumerator of internal array, doesn't physically hide the array, as the resulting IEnumerator can be cast back to int[].

**update #2:** My brother always use Clone() to return a copy of array. It is slowest, but he said it saved his career a few times (he works on a larger project in a team).

Comment: Can you show a sample of IEnumerable interface because i googled but never got a hit the gives a straight answer

Comment: Ivan, if you have internal array, you can return it as IEnumerable. Look to method GetValues() in my first example. That's easiest way. I am going to show another possibility (making whole class B enumerable) in the third example.

Comment: -1. Your code assumes `class A` is a wrapper (can have only one collection/array that it represents) or it returns the array (masked as `IEnumarable<>` which can still corrupt the original array and is against OOP principles (per your comments). You can always do `int[] list = (int[])GetValues()`

Comment: Without knowing more about Ivan's code this sample smells of needless complexity.

Comment: @ja72: My code doesn't assume that there is just one array in the class. Ivan just asked me to show how to make the whole class enumerable, and I showed the simplest way. Your other complaint is much more interesting. Yes, this is a classic question: If the provided enumerator can be cast back to array type, is it correct or not? In fact inheritance should not be used as a protection technique. If you want to physically hide the fact that it can be cast back, I can provide another example with yield command.

Comment: @AlKepp - The yield is an acceptable solution, and I agree that inheritance should not be used as a protection technique, and you downvoted my answer with the excuse the pure OOP protects better (which is baloney actually). Please reconsider your comments and votes and be more consistent.

Comment: @ja72: I thank you for your valuable comment. But still I think my solution is a bit better than yours. Although technically both are the same "insecure", my one transparently says "It's IEnumerable, so consider it as read-only." And I also add a note from my brother: He says that he always do Clone() on arrays, and that it saved his career a few times already. :-)